# What is the correct way to chain map_reduce calls in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have an Element model that belongs to User. I am trying to calculate the following hash: how many users have element count of 1, 2, 3, etc. The approach I take is to first generate a hash of {user -> num elements}, then I sort-of invert it using a second map-reduce.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Element.map_reduce(%Q{
  emit(this.user_id, 1);
}, %Q{
  function(key, values) {
    return Array.sum(values);
  }
}).out(inline: true).map_reduce(%Q{
  if (this.value > 1) {
    emit(this.value, this._id);
  }
}, %Q{
  function(element_count, user_ids) {
    return user_ids.length;
  }
}).out(inline: true)
```

This gives me an "undefined method `map_reduce'" error. I couldn't find the answer in the docs. Any help would be great.

Comment: What version of Mongoid are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I calculated the hash using aggregate instead mapreduce, first grouping by user, and then grouping again by elements count:

```
Element.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group" => {
      "_id" => "$user_id", "elements_count" => {"$sum" => 1}
    }
  },
  {
    "$group" => {
      "_id" => "$elements_count", "users_count" => {"$sum" => 1}
    }
  },
  { "$project" => {
        "_id" => 0,
        "users_count" => '$users',
        "elements_count" => '$_id',
    }
  }
])
```

This returns the following array:

```
[
 {"users_count"=>3, "elements_count"=>2},
 {"users_count"=>4, "elements_count"=>3},
 ...
]
```

If needed it can also be sorted using [$sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) operator

Comment: Unfortunately, not all operators can be used with project, so doesn't work in general